# In Google Cloud Firestore, how can I export storage also at the same time as collections?

Tags: firebase, import, google-cloud-firestore, export, storage

In Google Cloud Firestore we store collection data *and* storage data (jpeg files).  Is it possible to export them together and import them together?  We export like this:

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://backups-projectname
```

...and import like this into another project:

```
gcloud beta firestore import gs://backups-projectname/2019-06-28T18:18:37_6038/
```

It does, partially, work: the collection data shows up in the new location.  But the storage data doesn't.  Is the storage not included in the export?  Can it be included with a flag?  Or is there a separate command?

Note: I'm ***not*** talking about copying the files independently `gsutil cp -r`  I can already get the files into the Firestore Storage with that command, e.g.:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://projectname.appspot.com gs://projectname-86abf.appspot.com
```

I want the Firestore database and file storage to be exported as a ***single*** large object and imported from that same large object.  If that's not possible, what's the recommended way to accomplish this?